# start server from command prompt: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter

Tags: ignite

Ignite version : [2.14.0]

when i am starting apache ignite from command prompt, getting error

```
[15:38:37] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[15:38:38] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[2023-04-03T15:38:41,427][ERROR][main][IgniteKernal] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:114) ~[logback-classic-0.9.jar:?]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog(Logger.java:421) ~[logback-classic-0.9.jar:?]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog(Logger.java:430) ~[logback-classic-0.9.jar:?]
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:502) ~[logback-classic-0.9.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:77) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:170) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:278) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:267) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.<clinit>(AbstractLifeCycle.java:36) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.http.jetty.GridJettyRestProtocol.start(GridJettyRestProtocol.java:104) ~[ignite-rest-http-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.startProtocol(GridRestProcessor.java:1044) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.startHttpProtocol(GridRestProcessor.java:1015) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.start(GridRestProcessor.java:560) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1784) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1086) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1757) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1679) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1121) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1015) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:840) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:710) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:679) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.MessageFormatter
        ... 25 more
```

try to import few jars but did not worked. Expectation is to start apache ignite using command prompt.

Comment: Can you please say what you're trying to do and what you've done? It looks like you've enabled the REST API, which you didn't mention. How did you enable it?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with a [mcve]. "few jars" and the dump of an error message does not meet the criteria for a question.